# Automatic indentation/framing of nested theorems/proofs

Tags: environments, indentation

I'm a fan of python, and in the sadly common case where one creates new theorems, definitions, etc within the actual proofs of other theorems, I would like the "inner theorems" to be indented.

To this end, I've discovered [this solution](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2731), which provides a frame as well as indenting it.  However, that solution frames/indents everything, even base level theorems, which ended up being sort of ugly.  Is there a way to make it frame/indent only when you're nesting it in another proof, short of defining separate environments and doing it manually?

Not sure if it's important, but in case it is, my current setup is:

```
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,framed]{ntheorem}
\theorembodyfont{\small}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.6}
\renewcommand*\FrameCommand{{\color{gray}\vrule width 5pt \hspace{10pt}}}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newframedtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[page]
\newframedtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newframedtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newframedtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}

\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\newframedtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\newframedtheorem{ques}[thm]{Question}

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\newframedtheorem{proof}{Proof:}
```

---

Edit: my end solution was an lualatex modification of stuff posted in the checkmarked answer.  Because he edited it out, I'll vaguely requote the general idea here:

> Define two versions of your environments, `thm` and `frthm`, and
>   within the `proof` definition, redefine `\thm` to `\frthm` and
>   `\endthm` to `endfrthm`.  This is not as nice a solution as the
>   previous one, but it will technically work.

This is a MWE of that idea, written in lualatex for automation ( you'll have to modify the `tex.print` itself to change implementation-specific details like defining `\newtheorem` differently).

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{cool}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,framed]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.6}

\begin{luacode}
prefix = "fr"

function createEnvironments(environs)
    for sh, lo in pairs(environs) do
        tex.print("\\newtheorem{" .. sh .. "}{" .. lo .. "}")
        tex.print("\\newframedtheorem{" .. prefix .. sh .. "}{" .. lo .. "}")
    end
end

function redefineEnvironments(environs)
    for sh, lo in pairs(environs) do
        tex.print("\\def\\" .. sh .. "{\\" ..  prefix .. sh .. "}" )
        tex.print("\\def\\end" .. sh .. "{\\end" .. prefix .. sh .. "}")
    end
end
\end{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
--your list of shortcut="Environment"; fill in this table!
environList = { lem="Lemma" , prop="Proposition",proof="Proof"}

createEnvironments(environList)
\end{luacode}

\renewcommand*\FrameCommand{{\color{gray}\vrule width 5pt \hspace{10pt}}}
\appto\proof{% ... within the proof environment, we redefine the commands to point to the framed environments
\directlua{redefineEnvironments(environList)}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lem}
Layer 1
\end{lem}

\begin{proof}
Layer 0 stuff
\begin{prop}
Layer 1 starts getting embedded
\begin{lem}
This is an artefact: once you get into the first proof you start nesting no matter what
\end{lem}
\end{prop}

Layer 0 stuff
\begin{lem}
Another layer 1
\end{lem}

Can put layer 0 stuff here 
\begin{proof}
Layer 1 proof
\begin{prop}
Layer 2
\end{prop}
\begin{proof}
We conclude with a layer 2 proof
\end{proof}
\end{proof}

\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Explanation: I realized that making every theorem a framedtheorem had bad typesetting side-effects.  This new version creates both and redefines the former to the latter within the `proof` environment, where nesting is both likely to occur.  Of course, you can do the same within any other environment.

Comment: Can you add a full minimal working example that shows your solution completely.

Comment: Sorry about that; done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach, that uses `etoolbox` to tweak the definition of `\FrameCommand` from within the outermost theorem.  A complete MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framed]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{framed} % To define \FrameCommand
\usepackage{color} % To define \definecolor
\usepackage{lipsum} % For the dummy text
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.6}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % For \appto

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newframedtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[page]

\renewcommand*\FrameCommand{\relax} % By default, no framing occurs
\appto\thm{% ... but within the thm environment, FrameCommand is different
  \renewcommand*\FrameCommand{{\color{gray}\vrule width 5pt \hspace{10pt}}}
}


\begin{document}
\noindent \lipsum[1]
\begin{thm}
  Outer theorem
  \begin{thm}
    Theorem nested once
    \begin{thm}
      Theorem nested twice
    \end{thm}
  \end{thm}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

This results in the following appearance:

[image: nested theorem environments]

You'd need to add a similar call to `\appto` for each additional environment for which you wanted such nesting behavior.  (Unfortunately, the original solution I proposed, using `AtBeginEnvironment` adds the hook too early in the environment definition, so the `FrameCommand` gets redefined before it's used in the outermost environment too.  This version, using `\appto\thm`, is slightly less polite in that it hacks the opening of the environment by modifying the `\thm` command directly, but it adds the hook at the right moment.)

Comment: Hmm, the problem with the first solution seems to be that, `\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\def\mynesting{\vrule width 5pt \hspace{10pt}}}` automatically makes the proof environment always nested (even the first Proof and even when I redefined it back to \relax `\AtEndEnvironment`).  I could be doing it wrong, because doing essentially the same thing via lua works (and lets me do more general stuff), so that's probably the approach I'll be taking.

Comment: @scallops, See my edited answer: apparently (after testing it myself), `AtBeginEnvironment` takes effect earlier than I thought i did.  There's still a very simple solution, using `\appto` instead, that gets the appearance I think you wanted.

Comment: I like this new one as well.  Very short and sweet.  Thanks!

Comment: @BenLerner: This solution has a big problem. You can't use frame breaks. If the content results in a frame break you will get en error.

Comment: @Marco, I don't think this is the fault of my solution above, for two reasons: 1) if you comment out the `\renewcommand` and `\appto` commands, and add a bunch of `\lipsum` within the theorems, you'll see that the bare `ntheorem` styles yield either errors or an infinitely-long document.  Also, 2) the change I made to `\FrameCommand` is in keeping with the definition of the `leftbar` environment in `ntheorem`, so I doubt that's the cause...  I'm happy to edit the answer above to fix these bugs, but I don't know where to diagnose them :)  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @BenLerner: Sure it is really independent from your solution. You can't combine the provided `frame`.

Comment: I realized there was some undesirable behavior when making everything a framedtheorem, so I implemented a hybrid solution (MWE can now be found in original post).