# How can I apply a custom-defined theorem environment to nested theorems *only*?

Tags: macros, environments, theorems, nesting, proof-package

In [a previous thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202838/how-do-i-use-the-boxed-theorem-name-as-a-qed-symbol), I asked about the possibility of defining a custom theorem environment whose QED symbol would be a boxed version of the theorem's name/number/label. There, I was graciously provided with the following solution:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,xpatch}

\makeatletter
\let\qed@empty\openbox % <--- change here, if desired
\def\@begintheorem#1#2[#3]{%
  \deferred@thm@head{%
    \the\thm@headfont\thm@indent
    \@ifempty{#1}
      {\let\thmname\@gobble}
      {\let\thmname\@iden}%
    \@ifempty{#2}
      {\let\thmnumber\@gobble\global\let\qed@current\qed@empty}
      {\let\thmnumber\@iden\xdef\qed@current{#2}}%
    \@ifempty{#3}
      {\let\thmnote\@gobble}
      {\let\thmnote\@iden}%
    \thm@swap\swappedhead
    \thmhead{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    \the\thm@headpunct\thmheadnl\hskip\thm@headsep
  }\ignorespaces
}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{%
  \ifx\qed@thiscurrent\qed@empty
    \qed@empty
  \else
    \fbox{\scriptsize\qed@thiscurrent}%
  \fi
}
\renewcommand{\proofname}{%
  Proof%
  \ifx\qed@thiscurrent\qed@empty
  \else
    \ of \qed@thiscurrent
  \fi
}
\xpretocmd{\proof}{\let\qed@thiscurrent\qed@current}{}{}
\newenvironment{proof*}[1]
  {\def\qed@thiscurrent{\ref{#1}}\proof}
  {\endproof}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{nthm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\section{Title}

\begin{thm}
Pigs can fly.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
Would you doubt it?
\end{proof}

\begin{nthm}
Unnumbered.
\end{nthm}
\begin{proof}
What should we say?
\end{proof}

The following theorem will be proved later.

\begin{thm}\label{thm:later}
$P=NP$.
\end{thm}

Long text here.

\begin{proof*}{thm:later}
Oh, well! Should I really do it? We'll use the following lemma.

\begin{lem}
Something surely can fly.
\end{lem}
\begin{proof}
Clear.
\end{proof}
Now use the lemma and apply the well known identity
\[
1=0.\qedhere
\]
\end{proof*}
\end{document}
```

The result of that code is as follows:
[image]

Is it possible to modify the given code in such a way as to "detect nesting," i.e. so that the theorems/lemmas/propositions on the "top-level" (unnested) maintain their usual QED symbol while the theorems/lemmas/propositions on subsequent levels (those which are nested in the top-level ones) are designated as such with QED symbols which are the boxed names/numbers/labels of the theorems/lemmas/propositions?

Aside from the above code, I don't have a MWE because I have literally no idea how to go about coding such a thing. I have found a couple other forums on TeX.SX ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43765/adjust-environmentss-behaviour-when-nested) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30429/automatic-indentation-framing-of-nested-theorems-proofs)) which deal with formatting nested environments, but I was never able to adapt the code I have to the code provided therein.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to add a conditional that's true when a proof starts and change the code accordingly: if the conditional is false, we're not nesting, so we set `\qed@current` to `\qed@empty`, otherwise we use the same mechanism as in the other answer.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,xpatch}

\makeatletter
\let\qed@empty\openbox % <--- change here, if desired
\def\@begintheorem#1#2[#3]{%
  \deferred@thm@head{%
    \the\thm@headfont\thm@indent
    \@ifempty{#1}
      {\let\thmname\@gobble}
      {\let\thmname\@iden}%
    \@ifempty{#2}
      {\let\thmnumber\@gobble\global\let\qed@current\qed@empty}
      {\let\thmnumber\@iden
       \ifqed@inproof
         \xdef\qed@current{#2}%
       \else
         \global\let\qed@current\qed@empty
       \fi}%
    \@ifempty{#3}
      {\let\thmnote\@gobble}
      {\let\thmnote\@iden}%
    \thm@swap\swappedhead
    \thmhead{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    \the\thm@headpunct\thmheadnl\hskip\thm@headsep
  }\ignorespaces
}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{%
  \ifx\qed@thiscurrent\qed@empty
    \qed@empty
  \else
    \fbox{\scriptsize\protect\qed@thiscurrent}%
  \fi
}
\renewcommand{\proofname}{%
  Proof%
  \ifx\qed@thiscurrent\qed@empty
  \else
    \ of \qed@thiscurrent
  \fi
}
\newif\ifqed@inproof
\xpretocmd{\proof}{\let\qed@thiscurrent\qed@current\qed@inprooftrue}{}{}
\newenvironment{proof*}[1]
  {\def\qed@thiscurrent{\ref{#1}}\proof}
  {\endproof}
\def\debug{\show\qed@thiscurrent}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{nthm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\section{Title}

\begin{thm}
Pigs can fly.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
Would you doubt it?
\end{proof}

\begin{nthm}
Unnumbered.
\end{nthm}
\begin{proof}
What should we say?
\end{proof}

The following theorem will be proved later.

\begin{thm}\label{thm:later}
$P=NP$.
\end{thm}

Long text here.

\begin{proof*}{thm:later}
Oh, well! Should I really do it? We'll use the following lemma.

\begin{lem}
Something surely can fly.
\end{lem}
\begin{proof}
Clear.
\end{proof}
Now use the lemma and apply the well known identity
\[
1=0.\qedhere
\]
\end{proof*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @egreg! This is exactly what I had in mind. Follow-up question: I look at the code you provide and I have no idea how to come up with that. In particular, I'm familiar with using LaTeX as a typesetting environment (and with tweaking it slightly), but I'm completely ignorant regarding how to use it to "program" new environments; I'm unfamiliar with using if-then-else statements, etc. Can you recommend any resources (in English) to help me get familiarized with that aspect? Thanks again!

Comment: @twigg1313 That's a very long way to go. You can start with TeX by Topic (it's in the documentation part of TeX distributions with `texdoc texbytopic`) for the basics about TeX's way of doing things; then study macros wherever you find them. In some time you'll begin to understand what they are doing.